# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar el <?php?> para mostrar links cuando se cumpla cierta condicion?

Tags: php, laravel

```
//este es mi codigo, en la parte de accion es donde en vez de 
//mostrarme el link me muestra esto ',="" 6)="" }}'="" 

class="label label-success">revisar solicitud

     <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-striped task-table">
                    <thead>
                        <th width="25%">Id</th>
                        <th width="40%">Titulo</th>
                        <th width="20%">Accion</th>
                        <th width="20%">Estado</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($sol as $sol)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="table-text">
                                <div>{{$sol->id}}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="table-text">
                                <div>{{$sol->titulo}}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="table-text">
                                <?php echo ($sol->estado==0)?"<a href='{{ route('solicitudes.detalleTrabajador', $sol->id) }}' class='label label-success'>Atender solicitud</a>":"<a href='{{ route('solicitudes.detalleTrabajadorCompleto', $sol->id) }}' class='label label-success'>revisar solicitud</a>"; ?>

                            </td>
                            <td class="table-text">
                                <div><?php echo ($sol->estado==0)?"<font color='red'>No leído</font>":"<font color='blue'>leido</font>"; ?></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>      
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque no se aprecia ningún esfuerzo en depurar el código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2872/).

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Sería bueno que expliques esto: `<?php echo ($sol->estado==0)?"<a href='{{ route('solicitudes.detalleTrabajador', $sol->id) }}' class='label label-success'>Atender solicitud</a>":"<a href='{{ route('solicitudes.detalleTrabajadorCompleto', $sol->id) }}' class='label label-success'>revisar solicitud</a>"; ?>`... No uso Laravel... me pregunto si ese framework permite construir enlaces con valores entre `{{...}}` y poner código CSS dentro del enlace ¿?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe la opción de `@if` y `@php` para blade.

Ejemplo de uso de `@if`:

```
<td class="table-text">
@if($sol->estado==0)        
    <a href='{{ route('solicitudes.detalleTrabajador', $sol->id) }}' class='label label-success'>Atender solicitud</a>        
@else
    <a href='{{ route('solicitudes.detalleTrabajadorCompleto', $sol->id) }}' class='label label-success'>revisar solicitud</a>
@endif
</td>
```

[Documentación Laravel  blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade)